# How do I free up internal storage if I don't have any apps downloaded?

Tags: internal-storage

I have an Android Voyager, RCT6773W22B. It's version 5.0.

When I first got it, and years after that, I could download at least five apps downloaded at a time and have a great sum of pictures in my gallery. I would still have space after this. Over time, I would delete apps I didn't use anymore. If I wanted to download something else and there wasn't enough space, I would delete apps and/or pictures I don't need.

Now, I can't download anything due to internal storage. I have no apps, five pictures (not taken with the camera), and I've cleared the cache on everything except Chrome. It tells me my internal storage is completely full and I can't move anything to an SD card. What do I do?

Comment: Do you use **WhatsApp**? If you use, then you need to delete the media files from the _**WhatsApp**_ folder.

Comment: @PuspamAdak: You need to backup them somewhere first and then delete them from the WhatsApp folder. You cannot access them otherwise afterwards, as far as I know.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of reasons that can cause this:

- leftover artifacts from uninstalled apps or updates
- download content from apps (videos/ photos from chat applications, maps for navigation, audio files for language learning apps, etc)
- currently kept open browser tabs (my chrome had at one point 50 tabs, it reserved ~1.5gb of space even if closed it but kept the tabs)

If you do a backup of your contacts and other important data, you can try to reset it to factory settings with a wipe of all sd/ internal memory. 
If you have a pc to connect your phone by cable AND the knowledge, you could browse the file folders and find the culprit (I would still recommend to clean the files over the phone afterwards but its easier to find what is taking the space)
You could buy as a well a bigger sd card as a temporary solution.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought about the browser tabs needing so much space just for offline viewing.

Comment: Yes, find any apps that don't have files you care about, and "Clear Data" for them, which resets them as if you'd just first installed it.

Comment: Additionally to add to @EricDuminil . There are some file management apps that you can download and it will list all the files you have on your phone by largest to smallest allowing you to easily clear up some data. I didn't realise how many downloaded large PDF's I had on my phone and was able to delete them using the file management app.

Answer (score 8):

The old (original) applications that came preinstalled on your phone are stored in the operating system part of the flash. As new versions of those applications appear, they are installed in the user part of the flash.
One way to recover some of the "lost" space is to bring applications to the "original" version - the one from flash. This will clear the "new" version that is installed in the "user" flash, freeing space available to you.
Of course, this does means you run older versions of those applications, which is not optimal.
This problem is most critical on 4GB storage phones (old budget smartphones). Some of them have SD card hardware support, but you can't move applications from the internal memory to the flash.

Another relatively easy way to check the storage is to connect the phone to a PC via USB cable and activate on the phone the "file access" mode - you will see "Internal Storage" and "SD Card" sub-folders (or something similar).
Also, +1 for WhatsApp storage of images/videos/...

Comment: I have been able to successfuly clear space this way, especially with Google apps that often come pre-installed on Android phones.  In addition to reverting to factory "original" version, if it's an app you know you don't use, you can disable it as well, which I believe will prevent the updater from trying to re-install the newest version again that you just got rid of.

Comment: You need to disable automatic updates , otherwise your apps, even if disabled, will get automatically updated.  Only uninstalling can prevent apps from being automatically updated, and of course there's only so much you can uninstall.

Comment: @Milwrdfan: I forgot about "disabling" pre-installed applications - unfortunately, there aren't many applications that can be disabled on an old budget model (or the ones that can be easily disabled, and the ones for which you can be certain you won't break anything else won't save you much storage space)

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the very similar problem I was having with my old phone.
First, check your Storage in Settings for the information of what takes up your phone's space
Second, if First step doesn't help, instal 3rd-party app, like Disk Usage, and check from there

My suspicion is the .thumbnail files and the database

Comment: How would one install an app to a completely full internal storage?

Comment: oh damn, i forgot about that. thanks for reminding me @Ruslan, lmao, my bad

Answer (score 5):

I solved a similar problem in android 5 doing this:

1. Settings --> Apps.
2. Go to All apps tab.
3. Look for "Download Manager" or something similar (I do not know the exact translation). It has an arrow pointing down inside a blue circle.
4. Select it and clear cache. For me, it had more than 1GB cache when I found it.

Answer (score 4):

you can check what files or folders occupying storage from adb shell, and delete it from command line. for example (du) disk usage, (rm) remove:
`du -hxcd1 /storage/emulated/0`
`rm -r /storage/emulated/0/Android/data`

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is lots of residue files from apps that are redundant and previously uninstalled. Then I'd recommend one of those cleaning apps like clean master, ordinarily its not the sort of app I would regularly use by any means. But I managed to free up >1GB on one my tablets and the next thing I new I could install loads of apps again - to my surprise.

May be worth looking at your apps in settings as well to make sure there's no excessive disk usage from a particular app.