# Device storage gradually increases after Android update for no reason

Tags: updates, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have an Android smartphone whose internal storage memory get incrementally bigger after every software update for no obvious reason. I have looked everywhere over the Internet but the answers were pretty much suggestions that I have already encountered and tested.

The phone's memory is around 16 GBs. During each and every of the last four software updates the memory stands at about 14 GBs, leaving room for almost 2 free GBs. As several of my apps in the SD card get updated over the next days, they are normally saved in the phone storage and then I move them to the SD card once the update completes. During the course of approximately a month, as more apps are getting updated and consequently moved the storage gradually climbs up to nearly 15.5 GBs and my phone displays limited storage error and everything else that comes with it (e-mail does not refresh, no more apps get updated etc.). The only solution that seems the erase the memory back to the 14-14.5 GB range is another Android software update.

What I have tried so far (daily basis):

- Moving apps and old/unused files to external SD card.
- Cleaning cache from Android Settings, cleaner applications and by
  wiping the cache partition (blue screen as Android boots).

Comment: is it related to also increased data usage?

Comment: I don't think so, data usage increases normally according to my usage of the 3G network. Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: Nope. My problem is different https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/211929

Comment: But you can inspect your phone storage https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210216